# How to solve bad gateway errors when accessing a KVM VM from outside using Nginx?

Tags: nginx, networking, debian, kvm, home-assistant

Impossible to access a VM from the outside on KVM. Nginx give a bad gateaway.

Hi everyone,
I have a small home server to host files, VM and some bunch of stuff.
Recently I got into home automation with home assistant. Trying to access it from oustide my home network with a Nginx proxypass or a WireGuard VPN, I got a bad gateaway or a timeout.

I think it's a network configuration related problem since the VM is bridged on my network.
I can access it from my local network (xxx.xxx.xxx.5) but when I use wireguard to VPN on my network, the same IP gives me a timeout.
BUT, if I ping it, it automatically redirect on the host server (xxx.xxx.xxx.6).

So far, I'm using another computer to proxypass on another machine, which does work.
I'm looking forward to limit the number of machines on my network and emulate back HAOS on my KVM server on the "main server".

Any idea on how to solve that?
Thanks !